Does OpenMcdf supports multi threading?
Can someone explain if there is any limitation to use OpenMcdf in a multi-threaded environment?
We are trying to use OpenMcdf to open and read files multiple times from different applications/devices and want to have clarity if that can cause any performance issues.

Are you asking about thread safety? or the ability to open shared files? Regardless I do not see any performance issues, but rather risk of crashes or other serious bugs, possibly bugs that are very difficult to reproduce.

Can you show us how you intend to use the components of the OpenMcdf library? In general .NET components are not thread-safe, unless it's explicitly stated in the documentation that they are.
